# On SQL request by column

Tags: sql

I have different simple SQL request that return only one value. Example

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category
```

I would to get all these infos in a unique request, with a column by request...

I tried something like that but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT COUNT(C.CategoryId) As nbPeople, COUNT(P.PersonID) As nbCategories FROM Category C, Person P
```

This works but I get only one column, and a row by request

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Category
```

How Can I simply do that ?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible but it's likely to easier (and give better performance) to do it as a set of single selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SQL Server, you can try this:

```
SELECT ( select COUNT(C.CategoryId)
         from   Category C
       ) As nbPeople
,      ( select COUNT(P.PersonID)
         from   Person P
       ) As nbCategories
```

In Oracle for example, you need to add this at the bottom

```
FROM   dual
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I didn't know about the "FROM dual" in Oracle

Comment: @Gab: you are welcome. Oracle always demands a `from`. That's why they created the single row table `dual`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from
(select count(*) cnt1 
from Table1) t1
join 
(select count(*) as cnt2
from Table2) t2 on 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL like following:

```
SELECT '' AS [StatisticName], 1 AS [StatisticCount]
WHERE 1=0

UNION ALL

SELECT 'PersonCount', COUNT(*) FROM [Person] 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'CathegoryCount', COUNT(*) FROM [Category]
```

First select with WHERE 1=0 is for create column header names only and is not necessary.